# Problems using Spanish characters (á,é,ñ...) in REST api respoonse

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, jakarta-ee

I am having some issues while getting the response from REST api in my code. When I use POSTMAN,REST CLIENT, I can see the correct characters but when I call the service in my application, the characters are getting corrupted to some junk characters like Ã©������. I have used UTF-8 encoding as well.

But, When I call another external service which also has Spanish characters in the response, I can see correct Spanish characters in my application. This issue exists only on some services.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in some of the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: You should check the encoding at every single point of the data transmission.